# How to construct an imbalanced MNIST-dataset based on a pre-defined gini-coefficient?

Tags: python, mnist, imbalanced-data, gini

*My goal is to make different versions of the MNIST dataset with different pre-defined levels of imbalancedness. A gini-coefficient (range: 0-1) is a measure of imbalancedness of a dataset where 0 represents perfect equality and 1 represents perfect inequality.*

I want to construct a function in Python which uses the MNIST data and a target_gini_coefficient(ranges between 0-1) as arguments. The function should adjust the data distribution (removes cases of specific classes) in the most efficient way to reach the target_gini_coefficient. Most efficient means that it removes a minimum of cases to reach the target_gini_coefficient. If the gini-coefficient of the adjusted MNIST-dataset equal the target_gini_coefficient, the function returns the adjusted dataset. A target_gini_coefficient could for instance be: 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 etc.

Note: The target_gini_coefficient will always be higher than the gini-coefficient of the original MNIST dataset (= 0.129).

**IMPORTING DATA**
I have loaded the MINST dataset in the following way:

```
test_seq = [
   torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
   torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
]
test_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose(test_seq)
train_transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.RandomAffine(
        10, shear=10
    )] + test_seq)
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('.', train=True, download=True, transform=train_transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.MNIST('.', train=False, transform=test_transform),
    batch_size=args.test_batch_size, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('.', train=False, download=True, transform=test_transform)
```

**ORIGINAL DISTRIBUTION**
This is how the original dataset looks like:
[image: original dataset contains 60000 training samples over 10 classes (distributed as follows:)]

**GINI-COEFFICIENT**
I have calculated the gini-coefficient in the following way:

```
# Calculate the original class proportions
train_labels = np.array(train_dataset.targets)
class_counts = np.bincount(train_labels)
class_props = class_counts / float(len(train_labels))
print("Class proportions", class_props)
class_prop_sorted = np.sort(class_props)[::-1]
cumulative_prop = np.cumsum(class_prop_sorted)
# Calculate the Gini coefficient
lorenz_x = np.linspace(0, 1, len(class_prop_sorted))
lorenz_y = np.cumsum(class_prop_sorted) / cumulative_prop[-1]
# Calculate the area under the Lorenz curve
area_lorenz = np.trapz(lorenz_y, lorenz_x)    
# Calculate the Gini coefficient
original_gini = ((2 * area_lorenz) - 1)

print("Imbalanced Gini coefficient:", original_gini)
```

The orifinal class proportions =  [0.09871667 0.11236667 0.0993     0.10218333 0.09736667 0.09035
0.09863333 0.10441667 0.09751667 0.09915   ]
The original Gini coefficient = 0.12898888888888904

I have been working on this problem for a few days now, but my programming and math skills are leaking behind. Also chatGPT was not able to construct a working function. If someone has any example code or formula I might use this would be very helpfull. Help is really appreciated!!